# C# - thread-safe implementation of a class with fixed array (queue/buffer?) (ADD, REMOVE, MODIFY)

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm new to programming, threading and thread safe synchronization in general, been reading a lot and searching, found dozens of similar questions - however couldn't find anything that would help me out in the end - or either my lack of knowledge about the topic didn't allow me to notice/understand the answer.

I've created class with 3 data fields (string, int, double) and 1 **method** (will be used to calculate new value - which later will be compared to selected criteria for filtering).

Then I want my main thread to perform actions in such order:

1. Reads data (3 files) to selected data structure. - *let's ignore these*
2. Runs selected amount of threads (2 <= x <= n/4, n - record count in file), which will take records, perform **method** on them and if the result meets the criteria - record will be written to **results data structure**.
3. To the data structure, which was used to pass data via threads, inserts all read data.
4. Waits for all threads to finish.
5. Writes data from results structure to file. - *let's ignore these*

**Thread reqs:**

- When all data is processed, threads automatically finish the job. While at least a single thread is working, main thread is waiting for it to finish.
- Data to threads is passed via synchronized data structure: monitor. I need to implement it as a class or structure which contains add and remove methods.

  - Data inside the monitor class is stored to array (arr.size <= all data size / 2)
  - If an attempt is made to read/delete from the monitor when the internal array is empty or write/add when the internal array is full, the thread is blocked - via conditional synchronization, threads execute only after some condition is met, I assume. (Using lock, unlock, Monitor.Wait Pulse and PulseAll methods).
- **Result data structure** is the same as initial data structure, except no fixed array size. Data to result structure must be added in order.

At the moment I have this (pseudo-ish):

*Also I've been trying to search for different implementations of what I'm talking about and kept failing miserably, it's 7 AM now - so code is a mess, I excuse myself for that*

```
class Computer // 3 field class.
{
    public string _model { get; set; }
    public int _ram { get; set; }
    public double _screen { get; set; }

    double methodForFilterValue(Computer computer)
    {

        return computer._screen + computer._ram;
    }
}



class Computers // Monitor class.
{
    Computer[] _computers; // array of computers - buffer.
    int _bufferHead { get; set; } // circular buffer properties.
    int _counter { get; set; }
    int _bufferTail { get; set; }
    int _length { get; private set; }

    private readonly object _locker = new Object();

    Computers (int length)
    {
        _bufferHead = _bufferTail = -1;
        _length = length;
        _computers = new Computer[length];
        _counter = 0;
    }

    Computers(Computer[] computers)
    {
        _length = computers.Length;
        _computers = computers;
        _bufferHead = 0;
        _bufferTail = _length - 1;
        _counter = computers.ToList().Count;
    }

    Add(Computer computer)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if((_bufferHead == 0 && _bufferTail == _length - 1) || (_bufferTail +1 == _bufferHead))
            {
                //means Empty.
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_bufferTail == _length - 1)
                    _bufferTail = 0;
                else
                    _bufferTail++;
                _computers[_bufferTail] = computer;
                _counter++;
            }
            if (_bufferHead == -1)
                _bufferHead = 0;
        }
    }

    Remove()
    {
        lock (_locker){} -- not implemented yet.
    }
}

class ResultStructure // Result class - for filtered records, printing to file.
{
    public Computer[] _resultComputers;
    public int _capacity { get; set; }
    public int _counter { get; set; }

    private readonly object _locker = new Object();
    private const int INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 10;

    public ResultStructure()
    {
        _resultComputers = new Computer[INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
        _capacity = INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
        _counter = 0;
    }
    public ResultStructure(int length)
    {
        _resultComputers = new Computer[length];
        _capacity = length;
        _counter = 0;
    }

    public void AddSorted(Computer computer)
    {
        -- yet to be implemented also.
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size = 90; // single file size: 30 lines.
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(file_*.json");
        int selectedCriteria = 20; // each computer's methodForFilterValue() will have to result in a higher value than 20 for it to be added to resultStructure.

        Computers allComputers = new Computers(size/2);
        Computers[] computers = new Computers[filePaths.Length];
        ResultStructure result = new ResultStructure(size);

        **//STEPS:**

        **//1. Data read.**
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
        {
            computers[i] = ReadJson(filePaths[i]);
        }


        **//2. ??? - Need explanation on this part.**
        **//Basically this part about: iterating through each record in computers[i] - calling methodForFilterValue() function, checking if the result of that function is > 20 and if yes, add record to result._resultComputers array. Items should be added while leaving the array sorted. "AddSorted()"**

        **//3. Run threads - addAll items to the same data struct.**
        var threadsAdd = Enumerable.Range(0, filePaths.Length).Select(i => new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < computers[i]._computers.Length; j++)
            {
                allComputers.Add(computers[i]._computers[j]);
            }
        }));

        var threads = threadsAdd.ToList();

        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Start();
        }
        **//4. wait for all threads to finish**
        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }

        **5.** WriteToFile();

        Write("Program finished execution");
    }
```

Edit:

As asked will narrow it down to:
How to create thread-safe add, remove methods - run them on multiple threads, while in Computers class having limited size array - blocking threads when array is empty or full.
In total records: 90
, Computers class array = [45];

Should say also that I'm specifically required not to use concurrent collections.

[code if needed](https://pastebin.com/WZ0ggMXQ/)!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not going to use the built-in thread safe collections for this? After reading through your question it seems they would do everything you need.

Comment: Also, please try to narrow the question down to 1 question instead of 6. These 6 questions might warrant full answers of their own and now you risk people answering just a few of these and then there is no way to accept an answer here.

Comment: This question is a little hard to understand as there are so many requirements, sounds like a pipeline, if so TPL DataFlow. though honestly its hard to depick your solution from your problem and not think this is XY

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, I can't use built-in thread safe collections, have to specifically use limited size array and "monitor class" which has atleast 2 methods: add and remove (Computers class). Also I'm sorry once more and tried to narrow it down a bit or atleast sound more simple - you're correct saying that, though - I'll end up accepting the answer - any of those answered can lead to understanding the whole thing.

Comment: @TheGeneral I think it's way more simple - just maybe I ended up making it sound complicated with my explanations. It should be a simple concurrent data structure (sometimes also called a shared data structure) - just threads accessing shared resources - with the help of locks and synchronization.

Comment: Can you elaborate *why* you cannot use built-in types? I ask because there is likely hidden criteria or information in that reason that might guide answers.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, ofcourse - built in collections provide some thread-safety through the synchronized property and so on - which returns a thread-safe wrapper around the collection. The wrapper works by locking the entire collection on every add or remove operation - so it's for the sole reason of learning how to do it "by-hand" ... Instead of using tools - which help you achieve that :(

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Trying to understand myself - but I'd assume array is not thread-safe - if we were to run multiple threads, which will try acess the same code, we wouldn't get the results we want without wrapping code with lock() and synchronization, that's my guess.

Comment: No, there are a host of thread safe collections specifically built for this, see [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8). The ones named something Blocking will specifically allow you to try to dequeue an element and then block, waiting for one to become available (ie. some other thread enqueues one).

Comment: Also, "thread safe" is not a well-defined concept, you should make sure you define what kind of thread safety features you require. For instance, arrays themselves are thread safe in the sense that you cannot corrupt the *array*, making the *array* unusable. However, it is hard to reason about its contents without some kind of synchronization. A Dictionary, on the other hand, can easily be corrupted *itself* if you write to it from different threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to multithreading, the answer about what you should do is simple: [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) **every** time you access a shared resource. "Access" means read **and** write. "Shared resource" means every variable or field or property that is accessed by more than one threads concurrently. Use the same lock object to protect the same variable. Release the lock as soon as possible.

This advice is not enough for creating a performant application, nor is enough for avoiding deadlocks, but at least your data will not be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that some [concurrent collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent) exists in C# and should be usefull for you.

You should use :

```
ConcurentDictionary<string, Computer>
```

if you have a computer identifier.

Comment: Yes, I know - in this task specifically, I'm asked not to use cocurrent collections, though.

Comment: @Blank__ Do you know *why* you're being asked not to use concurrent collections? For instance, is this really something like an interview situation where you're required to show that you can write multithreaded code safely? Again, knowing *why* you cannot use these collections might give us some information about how to answer it. As right now, the most *obvious* answer to your question is "use the built-in concurrent collections".